# Cannot write random choice from list into text file

Tags: python, file-io

Really not sure what's not working here, I want python to choose a random name from the list, this works because I've print the variable.

I then want to store the random name in a text file. The file is there but it's just empty. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import random

names = "Balo", "Bandugl", "Baroro", "Cag", "Charoth", "Duglinglabat", "Dulko", "Fangot"

rand_name = random.choice(names)


c1= open( "character_one.txt", "w")

c1.write(rand_name)

c1.close
```

Why is python not writing the random choice to the text file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code looks fine except that you are not actually calling `c1.close` at the end.

You need to add `()` after it to do this:

```
import random

names = "Balo", "Bandugl", "Baroro", "Cag", "Charoth", "Duglinglabat", "Dulko", "Fangot"

rand_name = random.choice(names)

c1 = open("character_one.txt", "w")

c1.write(rand_name)

c1.close()
```

---

This is why it is a good idea to use a [with-statement](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) to open a file:

```
import random

names = "Balo", "Bandugl", "Baroro", "Cag", "Charoth", "Duglinglabat", "Dulko", "Fangot"

rand_name = random.choice(names)

with open("character_one.txt", "w") as c1:

    c1.write(rand_name)
```

Doing so ensures that the file is closed when you are done.

Comment: Thanks, knew it would be something stupid. Should probably sleep but oh well

Comment: Using [`with`](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) would be an even better idea.

Comment: @FredLarson - Yea, I probably should mention that.

Answer (score 1):

A great practice is to use `with`, as it INCLUDES the `close` method implicitly:

```
with open('file.ext', 'w') as c1:
    c1.write(rand_name)
```